# Lubuntu Drag & Drop Option

Tags: lubuntu, browser, drag-and-drop

I installed Lubuntu
The first thing I do after installing the OS, I build a link to the desktop.
I'm really a sad  because I can't drag and drop url link from browser to desktop , or any folder in Lubuntu. Maybe is some plugin, extension, software, app for lubuntu who can do this? If not , maybe you know other light linux OS for old PC who have this? Thank You.

Comment: You didn't tell us the release of Lubuntu you are referring to (and thus if using LXDE (16.04 & 18.04) or LXQT (18.10 onwards)).   The only other light linux OS supported here is Xubuntu which included 32bit as long as Lubuntu did.  *I can drag a copy of this page to my xubuntu desktop & it creates a link; which I quickly deleted as I think it looks untidy*

Comment: My OS is Lubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: It is very bad that Lubuntu does not support Drag & Drop Option because I like Lubuntu

Comment: I'm at a disadvantage in trying to help because I've never done what you're referring to, so am only guessing about your purposes. Lubuntu is built around `openbox` and I think here is the restrictions in Lubuntu (both LXDE & LXQt).  URL links are allowed, (i found info here helpful http://lxlinux.com/indexold.html#11 but this would not be automatic).  My attempts to drag & drop 'automatically' *mostly* failed, but I don't do it, have little experience & don't know `openbox`.  The extra code needed to make it automatic would negate the 'light' purpose of openbox I suspect.

Comment: I'm not a programmer, but I can't believe that this option is so complicated :)

Comment: I can add Drag & Drop link software on desktop, I can't add link only from browser

Comment: I can copy links from `firefox` to `leafpad` (on 18.04; or other editor) so possibly it's not a `openbox` limitation  (*I've never gone further than an editor where I can inspect & reduce link to remove tracking etc via macro/script*)

Comment: Yes I know. I'm copying a link to Leafpad, just like you, but it's TOTAL STUPID